# Why do I have to include the font files with Font-Awesome?

Tags: css, font-awesome

The Font-Awesome docs do not mention anywhere that other files need to be downloaded and included within a project so why are the icons missing?

I know that the font files *should* be within the relative path so Font-Awesome can *see* them, I understand that, but with reference to other techniques like combining and minifying css files and JavaScripts, why is it that there will more HTTP requests to get the fonts?

`[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (fontawesome-webfont.woff, line 0)`

Comment: If it didn't involve a font, they wouldn't have called it Font Awesome.

Comment: You need to include the font files as well. Font Awesome is a web font.

Comment: I'd vote to close this question because it should be obvious that you'd have to load a font....but I'll let it go. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can see that they do state that you need to copy the entire directory onto your webserver.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

> EASY: Default CSS
>
> Use this method to get the default Font Awesome CSS.
>
> 1. Copy the entire font-awesome directory into your project.

So just including the CSS file in your header isn't going to do much, because as others have pointed out.. it's a font. Think of it like Wingdings, so that's a font file.

Then the CSS basically sets the classes as background images, using the content but written using the font.

Minifying can cause some disruption to the paths of your CSS files. Basically, you need to make sure things are being referenced correctly. But firstly, ensure that the font files are on your webserver, and the CSS file of font-awesome is pointing to the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

The entire point of Font Awesome is that it provides icons in form of a font file. Usually that font file is in the correct spot in the right directory next to the CSS files. The CSS files are referencing those font files (because they have to, somehow).

If you're picking that folder structure apart and are serving the CSS file from a different location then you'll also need to take care that the relative references to the font files don't break.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps on [their website](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/).

Download [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome-4.3.0.zip).

Comment: The error I posted is the error I get when that is included.